# Young adult sci-fi novel about a teenager who electrocutes himself while working on a computer. Afterwards he has a "computer brain"

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, computers

Along with the information in the title, I can provide a few more details. I read this in the early to mid-nineties, and the cover art had a teenage boy who had his hands on his head with a few stylized "BZZZAP" onomatopoeia around his head.

My memory of the plot is hazy, but it dealt with a computer-savvy teenager who accidentally electrocuted himself while working on his computer. He found that he was able to easily ace his tests at school (specifically a math exam) because of this. I'm not sure if he was able to interface with internet, or if that's something I imagined he would be able to do while I was reading the book.

Comment: Please check the answers to [this similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/98806/5930) and let us know if any of them are the book you're thinking of.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yep, this is definitely the same book as in that user's question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like *Cybershock:  Totally Wired*, by David Lambert (1996).

[Amazon's summary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0874067413):

> When Jed is accidentally electrocuted while working on his computer, he's amazed to discover that the computer images no longer appear on the burned-out CRT but instead appear inside his head.  Even more amazing, he discovers that by thinking commands, he can operate his computer remotely. Jed's incredible new power brings him to a head-to-head confrontation with a crazed gunman—and himself.

There does not seem to be a cover image I can find online, even thought the book was apparently [scanned by Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=uS5VY-rTqsYC).  However, searching through the Google Books version comes up with multiple references to a math test:

> ["You think I needed to cheat to ace that stupid test?"](https://books.google.com/books?id=uS5VY-rTqsYC)

Comment: There isn't even a listing on ISFDb!

Comment: Wow! This is definitely the book I was looking for! I didn't remember the MC's name at all until I read this answer, but the moment I read this it all came back to me. Thanks!